# Overlapping attributes

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am making a map in QGIS to show different program interventions in a number of districts. There are  programs overlapping in some districts. How can I make solid fill for a give program and diagonal pattern fil to show in a given district that we are running multiple interventions

Comment: Are you asking "how to categorize a layer based on two attributes"?

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html

Comment: Thanks Eric....Let me be clear of my question... we have two programs running in different districts, HIV/AIDS and Nutrition. In most districts(unique Pcode) we are running a single program either nutrition or HIV/AIDS. However in few the programs overlaps and we run two programs. In my categorization, I have yellow simple fill for Nutrition and Diagonal pattern fil for HIV/AIDS. Is it Automatic to see both fill for Districts with overlapping programs?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say anything about how your data (attributes) are structured:

1. Do you have a field with three values, thus something like: 1=HIV/AIDS, 2=Nutrition, 3=Both?
2. Or do you have a field `HIV/AIDS` and another one `Nutrition`, each with a true/false value?
3. Anything else?

There are several ways to do that, here two options based on the cases described above:

In the first case, apply a categorised renderer with the attribute field as value and manually set yellow fill for value 1, diagonal pattern for value 2 and a third category where you apply both styles using two symbol layers.

In the second case, duplicate the layer and set a rule based filter for each of them based on your condition: when `HIV/AIDS=true` for one layer, `Nutrition=true` for the other layer and style them accordingly, see screenshot:

[image]